# why $F(a^2) \subset F(a)$?

Tags: field-theory

I have some  doubt in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231085/how-do-i-prove-fa-fa2)

**Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$. If $a \in E$ has a minimal polynomial of odd degree over $F$, show that $F(a)=F(a^2)$.**

let $n$ be the degree of the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $a$ over $F$ and $k$ be the degree of the minimal polynomial $q(x)$ of $a^2$ over $F$

Since $a^2 \in F(a)$, We have $F(a^2) \subset F(a)$, then $k\le n$

I don't understand  why  $F(a^2) \subset F(a)$?

**My thinking**: Take $ a  \in \mathbb{R} $, $a \subset a^2 \implies F(a) \subset F(a^2)$

Comment: What assumptions of the prompt haven't you used yet? The fact that you can assume the minimal polynomial is essential.

Comment: $F(a^2)\subset F(a)$ because $F\subset F(a)$ and $a^2\in F(a)$ and $F(a)$ is a field

Comment: hi jasmine; do you mean to ask why $F(a^2)\subset F(a)$, or why $F(a)\subset F(a^2)$? the first of these holds without any hypotheses about the minimal polynomial of $a$, while the second requires an additional hypothesis in general. (I ask because in your "my thinking" section you seem to be trying to prove $F(a)\subset F(a^2)$, and not the other way around. I will additionally note that your argument there is not clear; what do you mean when you write $a\subset a^2$?)

Comment: take $a = \mathbb{R}$ i mean for example $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: @J.W.Tanner u mean $F(a^2)$ is not field  Am i right ?

Comment: oh, I think I see your confusion. $a$ is an *element* of $E$, not a subset. to get some intuition for what's going on, try to consider the following two cases: let $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$. for the first case, let $a=\sqrt{2}$. for the second case, let $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$. reflect upon the fields $F(a)$ and $F(a^2)$ for these values of $F$ and $a$. 

also, in response to your question to @J.W.Tanner, $F(a^2)$ **is** a field. do you know what the notation $F(b)$ means for $b\in E$?

Comment: thanks u got it @AtticusStonestrom  For  $a = \sqrt 2$, $ F(a)=\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt 2})$ contain basis  $\{1, \sqrt 2\}$ but  $ F(a^2)=\mathbb{Q}(2)$ contain basis $1 \implies F(a^2) \subset F(a)$  Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine right! so in that case $F(a^2)\subset F(a)$ but $F(a)\not\subset F(a^2)$. now, what about when $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$? *hint:* for one direction, note that $[\sqrt[3]{4}]^2=2\sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: it will  be reversed  $ F(a) \subset  F(a^2)$ @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: indeed, that relation holds, but we also have $F(a^2)\subset F(a)$ – can you see why? in particular, since $F(a^2)\subset F(a)$ and $F(a)\subset F(a^2)$, this means $F(a^2)=F(a)$ in this case

Answer (score -1):

Credit : Atticus Stonestrom( comment section)

For  $a = \sqrt 2$, $ F(a)=\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt 2})$ contain basis  $\{1, \sqrt 2\}$ but  $ F(a^2)=\mathbb{Q}(2)$ contain basis $1 \implies F(a^2) \subset F(a)$